# Not able to catch error from AWS sdk [S3]

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im trying to download a file from S3 which doesn't exist on S3. I expect a error in this scenario and im also getting that error from aws-sdk i.e.

**/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
throw err;
^

NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.**

But the issue is, im not able to catch this error. If you check the code below, my listener request.on gets called and when i call reject in that the promise doesn't return from method downloadFontInfoFileFromS3 with reject.

Is there any way i can catch the error and gracefully reject the promise from downloadFontInfoFileFromS3 function?

```
downloadFontInfoFileFromS3(fileKey) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sThree = new awsSDK.S3();
        const options = {
            Bucket: awsConf.bucket,
            Key: fileKey,
        };
        const downloadFilePath = SOME_PATH
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(downloadFilePath);

            const request = sThree.getObject(options);

            const download = request
                .createReadStream().pipe(file);

            // called when error in aws-sdk
            request.on('error', (error) => {
                logger.error('Failed to download file from S3:', error.message);
                reject(error);
            });

            download.on('error', (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });

            download.on('finish', () => {
                resolve(downloadFilePath);
            });
            // the synchronous code that we want to catch thrown errors on
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the promises which are now part of the aws-sdk? See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/ which will allow you to write 'sThree.getObject(options).promise()' rather than handling the wrapping yourself

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. Turns out I wasn't setting the error handler in the correct place.

Currently, you have:

```js
// INCORRECT. Won't work

const download = request.createReadStream().pipe(file);

download.on('error', (error) => {
    reject(error);
});
```

But you actually need to set the error handler on the stream, **before you begin piping**. Like this:

```js
// Correct!

const download = request.createReadStream(); // notice the `.pipe()` has been removed

download.on('error', (error) => {
    reject(error);
});

// now you can begin piping to the file
requestStream.pipe(file);
```

If you try setting the event handler after the pipe has begun, the error will "bypass" any `try`/`catch` or Promise `.catch` handlers you specify. Quite frustrating!

Check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1436#issuecomment-290445593) for another example.

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = s3.getObject({ Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME, Key: url }).createReadStream();

data.on("error", (err) => {
    if (err)
        return next(customError("Invalid Url", 400));
});
data.pipe(res);
```

Right Because Error is occourd when data in pipe.